# D3: am I using scale.invert() wrong?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 to build a timeline. In some of the data I'm feeding it, events are very close to each other so that they overlap in the visualization, much like the first two dots in this simplified example:
[image]

I'm naively trying to avoid this by checking the underlying data points for a possible overlap with their neighbor and adding the width of a dot if necessary:

```
for(var i = 1; i<dataset.length;i++){
  if((xScale(dataset[i])-xScale(dataset[i-1]))<(2*dotRad)){
    dataset[i]+=xScale.invert(2*dotRad);
  }
}
```

However, as shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4wrs7g8/2/), `xScale.invert(2*dotRad)` adds less distance between the first two dots than I'd expect, they shouldn't overlap anymore. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work correctly because the scale gives you a position, not a difference between positions. That is, when inverting you're getting the datum for a particular pixel location, not a difference between two pixel locations. It's safer to compute the new position (in pixels, by adding the offset) and then invert that:

```
for(var i = 1; i<dataset.length;i++){
  var diff = xScale(dataset[i]) - xScale(dataset[i-1]);
  if(diff < 2*dotRad) {
    var add = 2 * dotRad - diff;
    dataset[i] = xScale.invert(xScale(dataset[i]) + add);
  }
}
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s4wrs7g8/5).

Your code will sort of work in the special case where the domain and range start with 0 (see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s4wrs7g8/6)), but as you're adding `2 * dotRad` regardless of the actual overlap, the dots will actually be spaced out more than they need to be.